# TypeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute '__getitem__' // getting columns?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to open a .csv file and put each column in different list:

```
import csv
CSV = csv.reader(open("AAPL.csv","rb"))
column1 = CSV[0]
column2 = CSV[1]
column3 = CSV[2]
column4 = CSV[2]
column5 = CSV[4]
column6 = CSV[5]
```

Here is my `AAPL.csv`:

```
Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume   Adj Close
2013-09-27  874.82  877.52  871.31  876.39  1258800  876.39
2013-09-26  878.3   882.75  875     878.17  1259900  878.17
2013-09-25  886.55  886.55  875.6   877.23  1649000  877.23
2013-09-24  886.5   890.1   881.4   886.84  1467000  886.84
2013-09-23  896.15  901.59  885.2   886.5   1777400  886.5
2013-09-20  898.39  904.13  895.62  903.11  4345300  903.11
2013-09-19  905.99  905.99  895.4   898.39  1597900  898.39
2013-09-18  886.35  903.97  883.07  903.32  1934700  903.32
2013-09-17  887.41  888.39  881     886.11  1259400  886.11
2013-09-16  896.2   897     884.87  887.76  1336500  887.76
.............................................................
end of file:
.............................................................
2012-06-29  574.96  58013   572.20  580.07  2519500  580.07
2012-06-28  565.90  566.23  557.21  564.31  1920900  564.31
2012-06-27  567.70  573.99  566.02  569.30  1692300  569.30
2012-06-26  562.76  566.60  559.48  564.68  1350200  564.68
2012-06-25  567.33  568.09  557.35  560.70  1581600  560.70
```

When I run my code, it returns me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/misha/Documents/finance/prices/some_csv.py", line 3, in <module>
    column1 = CSV[0]
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Is there any pythonic way to open a .csv file and put each column in different list not using attribute `getitem`?

Thanks.

NOTE: and also i need to skip first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `csv.reader` instance is an iterable over the lines of the CSV file. If you want each column in a separate list, you can use the `zip` function:

```
import csv

with open("AAPL.csv", "rb") as f:
    CSV = csv.reader(f)

    header = next(CSV) # read the header row
    column_data = zip(*CSV) # read data and arrange by columns instead of by rows

# do stuff with column_lists
```

Note that this reads the whole file in at once. If you have a very large amount of data in your file, you might want to redesign your algorithms to work on the data one row at a time as you iterate over the `CSV` object, so you don't need to hold it all in memory.

Comment: Since the OP wants to store lists of column values, then I guess memory is not an issue.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my intention was mostly to ask "Are you sure you really want lists of the columns? The data's not natively organized that way." The questioner seemed to be taking it for granted that the data was organized by column, and it may be that whatever they had planned to do with the column lists can be done just as easily row by row. (For instance, they might have been planning on `zip`ping up some of the columns to iterate over them.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import csv
CSV = csv.reader(open("AAPL.csv","rb"))
for col in CSV:
    column1 = col[0]    
    column2 = col[1]
    column3 = col[3]
```